# Java, Generics and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a basic question on genericity, Inheritance and Interfaces.

Given the following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Generics {

    private Class1 obj1 = new Class1();

    public Generics() {
        Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
        Class2 obj2 = new Class2();
        Class2 obj3 = new Class2();
        Class2 obj4 = new Class2();

        List<Class2> obj1Children = new ArrayList<Class2>();

        obj1Children.add(obj2);
        obj1Children.add(obj3);
        obj1Children.add(obj4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generics g = new Generics();
    }


    private class Class1 implements I1 {

        private List<I2> children;

        @Override
        public List<I2> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        @Override
        public void setChildre(List<I2> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }
    }

    private class Class2 implements I2 {
    }

    private interface I1 {
        List<I2> getChildren();
        void setChildre(List<I2> children);
    }

    private interface I2 {
    }
}
```

in Class1 if you change the line :

```
    private List<I2> children;
```

with

```
    private List<Class2> children;
```

Then I have a compile error telling me that it cannot cast List to List.

I'm confused because I thought the whole point of interfaces was to get rid of the implementation side of the thing.

Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: Further reading: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I1` clearly defines a method that returns a type of `List<I2>`. You can't change that for any reason in the implementing class, to return `List<Class2>`; that's the whole point of an interface. Your contract for implementing `I1` forces you to return a type of `List<I2>` under any circumstance.

Apart from the restriction that the interface implementation places on you, you should also know that "generics" are not forgiving; the `I2` in `List<I2>` cannot be cast to anything else. Not even a class in the same hierarchy. The typesafety provided by java is quite strict in that regard

Consider this:

1. `Class2` is-a `I2`
2. `List<Class2>` defines a typesafe collection of `Class2`s
3. `List<I2>` defines a typesafe collection of `I2s`
4. Java will not, at any point allow `List<Class2>` be substituted for `List<I2>`. Not in a variable declaration, a method argument or method return value

Comment: This is half of the answer. The other half relies in the fact that generics won't extend each other. `List<Class2>` doesn't extend `List<I2>`.

Comment: Answer in progress @LuiggiMendoza :)

Comment: Ok, even if I risk passing for a complete noob I don't understand you're comment @LuiggiMendoza. I understand that `List<Class2>` does not extend `List<I2>` but on the other hand `Class2` implements `I2` meaining that any relevent information to process an `I2` is also present on `Class2` therefore allowing to use `Class2` instances anywhere `I2` is specified. Or is it that we're not talking about the same step in the process (compile time for you and runtime for me) ?

Comment: @Marco My comment means that `List<Class2>` does not pass the IS-A test for `List<I2>`. If you declare you return a `List<I2>` you cannot return a `List<Class2>`. But if you declare you return an `I2` you can return a `Class2`.

Comment: @Marco - Allow me to clarify in the answer (I'm clearly not doing a good enough job as-is)

Comment: Thanks both of you. Now I understand it a little better, I'll play around with what you told me a hopefully come up with a solution that will be compliant with language constraints. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In the your code you mention return type is `<I2>`. But If you want your method will get 
any data type as the parameter than go with Object Simple one.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem in the Class1.setChildren() implementation: it accepts any implementation of I2 but your inner List only accepts the Class2 implementation.